# What is the Ubuntu Cloud Archive?

Tags: cloud, openstack

Reading the announcement [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2012-August/000160.html) , i didn't understood the part here

> The **Ubuntu Cloud Archive also makes its debut** - essentially  an online
>   software repository from which administrators can  download the latest
>   versions of OpenStack for use with the  latest long-term support (LTS)
>   release of Ubuntu.

What exactly does it mean and where is it deployed or used.

Answer (score 4):

It's a distribution mechanism for OpenStack on Ubuntu Server LTS releases.

> Canonical’s Ubuntu Cloud archive allows users the ability to install newer releases of OpenStack on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS (and the dependencies) as they become available up through the next Ubuntu LTS release (presumably 14.04). Bug processing and patch contributions will follow standard Ubuntu practice and policy where applicable.
>
> Canonical commits to maintaining and supporting new OpenStack releases for Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS in the Ubuntu Cloud archive for at least 18 months after they release. Canonical will stop introducing new releases of OpenStack for Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS into the Ubuntu Cloud archive with the version shipped in the next Ubuntu Server LTS release (presumably 14.04).
>
> They will maintain and support this last updated release of OpenStack in the Ubuntu Cloud archive for 3 years, i.e. until the end of the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS lifecycle.

Sources:

- [ServerTeam/CloudArchive - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive)
- http://blog.canonical.com/2012/09/14/now-you-can-have-your-openstack-cake-and-eat-it/